# Fastest way to load 10Gb of RDF into virtuoso triplestore?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso, triplestore

Using

```
Virtuoso Open Source Edition (multi threaded)
Version 6.1.6.3127-pthreads as of Jan 14 2013
Compiled for Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

what would be the fastest option to load a single 10Gb RDF file into a virtuoso triple store? With the defaults configuration the process did not finish within a day.

So far I gathered the following options:

1. Using the web interface, using the [DB.DBA.RDF_LOAD_RDFXML_MT](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_rdf_load_rdfxml_mt.html)
2. Using 1. with the [isql-vt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/ISQL-VT.1.html) console
3. Using the web interface with [DB.DBA.TTLP_MT](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ttlp_mt.html)
4. Using 3. with the [isql-vt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/ISQL-VT.1.html) console
5. Using "Quad Store Upload" in the conductor web interface
6. Download from an URL

There are a couple of others, as can be found here: http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert.

What would be the preferred or canonical way to load a large amount of triples in a transactional manner from a single file that is available on the filesystem?

Comment: We document a number of [performance tuning settings](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning), which are key to proper performance -- and the lack of which would explain your day-plus 10GB load time.

Answer (score 3):

We have the [Virtuoso RDF Bulk Load functions](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) for loading large amounts of RDF data, which call the `TTLP` and `RDFXML_LOAD` functions under the covers, but allow for better management of the load process.

You should also consider upgrading to the [Virtuoso Column Store release 7.1](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload) (or later) which brings significant performance improvements.